# In Electron, how to include only specific node_modules with electron-packager?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, electron

I'm try to packaging my electron app, and it requires mqtt and node-notifier module.
So I want to do is exclude all node_modules except them.

Let's assume that I want to exclude these files from packaging:

- npm-debug
- gulpfile.js
- .vscode

So setting --ignore option like this:

```
--ignore='npm-debug|gulpfile\.js|\.vscode'
```

working fine. But additionally excluding node_modules except mqtt and node-notifier, I don't know how to make regex!

```
--ignore='npm-debug|gulpfile\.js|\.vscode|^((?!node_modules/mqtt).)$'  // NOT WORKING
```

Only checking node_modules, /^((?!node_modules/mqtt).)$/ is work, but combine them into single regex line, it's not working.

I know my regex was wrong, but I tried every combination of regex characters and my imagination, every attempt was failed and couldn't found any solution on google.

This is [Regex Testing site](http://regexr.com/3f6c9), you can see where am I stucked.

Any advice will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you have an **ignode** instaead of **ignore** in the second code you'v eposted. In any case, I usually save all modules with `--save-dev` and add them to my package.json accordingly, so that when I run electron-packager it automatically packages them all with no issues.

Comment: @briosheje That is just typo, I will update it later. Anyway me also, already set dependencies: mqtt and node-notifier, and others are all devDependencies. But when I run electron-packager, they are still inside of packaged app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From packager [github page](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager)

> Be careful not to include `node_modules` you don't want into your final app. If you put them in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json`, by default none of the modules related to those dependencies will be copied in the app bundles. (This behavior can be turned off with the `--no-prune` flag.)

From electron-packager [API page](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#prune) about `--prune` flag

> Runs the package manager command to remove all of the packages specified in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json` from the outputted Electron app.

You should be able to simply put all packages except `mqtt` in `devDependencies` and run packaging