# How to reduce Electron package size that exceeds more than 600 mb

Tags: javascript, electron, package.json, electron-builder, electron-packager

I see this is because of node-modules and application is packaged with some unwanted stuffs for running. Current file size is 600 mb but I want it to be less than 200 mb.

I suspect --no-prune populates all the node-modules in package that is built, but I need only specifies node-modules in the package that is built

I tried removing unwanted packages in package.json, it doesn't help me either

**after refactoring**

```
 "bundledDependencies": [

    "fs",

    "os",
    "path",

    "regedit",
    "request",
    "start",
    "xml2js",
    "util",
    "replace",
    "process",
    "fs",
    "console"

  ],
**before refactoring**
 "bundledDependencies": [
    "archiver",
    "child_process",
    "fs",
    "node-wget",
    "os",
    "path",
    "ping",
    "regedit",
    "request",
    "start",
    "xml2js",
    "util",
    "replace",
    "process",
    "fs",
    "console",
    "electron",
    "electron-builder",
    "electron-packager"
  ],
```

this didn't help me either

**package.json**

```
{
  "productName": "xyz",
  "description": "something",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",

    "builderForWindows": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname clientsettings . --executable-name abc --no-prune",
    "builderForLinux": "electron-packager --out Linx64 --overwrite --platform linux --appname clientsettings .  --executable-name abc --no-prune"
  },
  "author": "xyz",
  "devDependencies": {
    "archiver": "^2.1.1",
    "asar": "^2.0.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "console": "^0.7.2",
    "electron": "^4.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.41.0",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "node-wget": "^0.4.2",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "ping": "^0.2.2",
    "regedit": "^3.0.2",
    "replace": "^1.1.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^4.1.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19"
  },
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "archiver",
    "child_process",
    "fs",
    "node-wget",
    "os",
    "path",
    "ping",
    "regedit",
    "request",
    "start",
    "xml2js",
    "util",
    "replace",
    "process",
    "fs",
    "console",
    "electron",
    "electron-builder",
    "electron-packager"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "appdata-path": "^1.0.0",
    "targets": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at your app bundle to see what actually is getting included. You might be surprised.

Comment: App Bundle has some unnecessary node modules(ex:electron-packager,electron-builder),why do I need them after its bundled, how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> App Bundle has some unnecessary node
>   modules(ex:electron-packager,electron-builder),why do I need them
>   after its bundled, how to get rid of them?

Everything listed in "bundledDependencies" will be included in the app bundle.

```
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "archiver",
    "child_process",
    "fs",
    "node-wget",
    "os",
    "path",
    "ping",
    "regedit",
    "request",
    "start",
    "xml2js",
    "util",
    "replace",
    "process",
    "fs",
    "console",
    "electron",
    "electron-builder",
    "electron-packager"
  ],
```

---

```
  "builderForWindows": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform
 win32 --appname clientsettings . --executable-name abc --no-prune",
```

Specifying "no prune" – see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156640/840992

> Be careful not to include node_modules you don't want into your final app. If you put them in the devDependencies section of
>   package.json, by default none of the modules related to those
>   dependencies will be copied in the app bundles. (This behavior can be
>   turned off with the --no-prune flag.)

From electron-packager API page about --prune flag

> Runs the package manager command to remove all of the packages specified in the devDependencies section of package.json from the
>   outputted Electron app.